# gifs in carousal are not lazy loading

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, lazy-loading, carousel

I'm  using bootstrap carousal and there are some images in slides that I need to lazy load.
the gifs that I am using are not lazy loading.
im using 
http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload this plugin for lazy loading
can there be any issue.
I dont see any errors on console.

```
$("img.lazy").lazyload();
$('#carousel-custom').on('slide.bs.carousel', function(e) {
    $("img.lazy").lazyload();
});
```

and html markup

```
    <div id='carousel-custom' class='carousel slide' data-ride='carousel'>
    <div class='carousel-outer'>
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class='carousel-inner'>
            <div class='item active'>               
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center lazy-img-container pull-right">
                        <img alt="img" src="/assets/gifs/icon-Engage.gif" class=" lazy" />
                        <img alt="img" src="/assets/gifs/icon-Identify.gif" class=" lazy" />
                        <img alt="img" src="/assets/gifs/icon-Profit.gif" class=" lazy" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='item'>
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center lazy-img-container pull-right">
                        <img alt="img" src="/assets/gifs/icon-Engage.gif" class=" lazy" />
                        <img alt="img" src="/assets/gifs/icon-Identify.gif" class=" lazy" />
                        <img alt="img" src="/assets/gifs/icon-Profit.gif" class=" lazy" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='item'>
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center lazy-img-container pull-right">
                        <img alt="img" src="/assets/gifs/icon-Engage.gif" class=" lazy" />
                        <img alt="img" src="/assets/gifs/icon-Identify.gif" class=" lazy" />
                        <img alt="img" src="/assets/gifs/icon-Profit.gif" class=" lazy" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class='carousel-indicators'>
        <li data-target='#carousel-custom' data-slide-to='0' class='active'>
        </li>
        <li data-target='#carousel-custom' data-slide-to='1'>
        </li>
        <li data-target='#carousel-custom' data-slide-to='2'>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Please write code here.

Comment: code is added to Question.